# Zurb foundation 6 , what-input.min.js file functionality

Tags: zurb-foundation

Id like to know the relevance of `what-input.min.js` include in Zurbs foundation-6 framework , in the `js/vendor` directory , this is because i keep getting an 404 not found error not loading while running the site ,  `... js/vendor/jquery.min.map` file , is there any connection ?

Comment: You can check the repo on Github: https://github.com/ten1seven/what-input. It's pretty well explained there.

Comment: Don't know what `what-input.min.js` is used for, but the `.map` not loading is unrelated. You only see this when you have developer tools opened, your browser should not attempt to download `.map` files otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the .map file which is used to map a minified file back to the original. It is available for download from jquery's site. Source maps are can be ignored in inspector settings which makes sense when you don't plan on debugging minified javascript files

It is unrelated to the source map file 404 but what-input.min.js is a JS library "to watch for mouse, keyboard and touch events"

They have a github page with more documentation: https://github.com/ten1seven/what-input

and a demo: 
https://ten1seven.github.io/what-input/ 
"Tab, click or tap the links and form controls to see how What Input allows them to be styled differently"

Comment: Greetings. Please check out [Take a tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Your answer is in another castle: When is an answer not an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370)

Comment: @Drew Thanks for the details

Comment: Thanks for the demo.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem on every site when using JointsWP with Foundation 6 framework. I finally just figured it out. I turned off css source mapping and still received the error. It turns out that it wasn't lying to me and the js file really does not exist where it is trying to load it from:

/vendor/what-input/what-input.min.js

But it is under the dist folder within that same directory. So if you find your enqueue-scripts.php file where the what-input.min.js is loaded, you can fix the directory path to:

/vendor/what-input/dist/what-input.min.js

And no more 404!